# freshly created partition missing even after partprobe, shows no such device or address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, fdisk, parted

On Ubuntu 14.04 I am trying to create new partitions but it's failing to create the filesystem

**fdisk -l /dev/sde**

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sde'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sde: 299.0 GB, 298999349248 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36209 cylinders, total 583983104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1               1   583983103   291991551+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

But

```
partprobe /dev/sde1
Error: Error opening /dev/sde1: No such device or address
```

And

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/sde1
mkfs.xfs: cannot open /dev/sde1: No such device or address
```

The device exists, although the device nodes seem strange

```
ls -la /dev/sde*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 64 Jan 18 16:43 /dev/sde
cr-------- 1 root root 8, 65 Jan 17 09:20 /dev/sde1
cr-------- 1 root root 8, 66 Jan 17 09:20 /dev/sde2
```

Comment: Try running `partprobe` without any arguments - so it checks for any new partitions.  Do `cat /proc/partitions` - this list all disks and the partitions on them (that Linux knows about) with their sizes - is it there?  If it's there, then you can create a filesystem on it (eg. `mkfs.ext4`).  First when there is a recognizable filesystem on the partition, will it be automatically mounted (and opened in the file-browser).  Note: External drives may "move around" with each mount - look for a partition of the right  size when you list /proc/partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/dev/sde` corresponds to a removable device, unplug it and remove any remaining device nodes (`rm /dev/sde*`). Then reconnect it and allow the system to create the device nodes properly.

On the other hand, if `/dev/sde` is an internal device, remove the device nodes and reboot your system. This should allow the system to recreate the device nodes properly.

Answer (score 3):

There is a warning displayed by `fdisk`:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sde'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

You must use `gdisk` or `parted` with GPT disks.

Comment: @roaima What sector 1 means here in the MBR is that the whole disk is "controlled" by GPT. The first GPT partition `/dev/sde1` should indeed no start at sector 1 (rather 2048 than 8192 but it doesn't matter much)

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry. Over thinking it.